# Elm Import of Js libraries

Tags: elm

I am new to elm and have been reading through the Decode library at

> https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/eb6ecefb9e001a58746110cdda7e7b366e577b2f/src/Json/Decode.elm

However I am a bit confused on line 55 they expose a library that seems to be linked to a javascript file ( Elm.Kernel.Json) in addition they use a variable like Elm.Kernel.Json.decodeString that seems to be linked to a javascript varable called _json_decodeString in the corresponding file.

1. How did they import a js library into elm?
2. How do they relate the *json* variables to those in the elm file?

Pretty sure I am missing something but don't know what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elm compiles to JS and ultimately relies upon JS code to work. But access to JS code is severely restricted in order to provide the guarantees of type safety.

So in practise the only sanctioned way to use JS is via a [port](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html).

What you are looking at are the core Elm libraries, and these use special techniques to access JS libraries directly. These techniques are undocumented as they are not supposed to be followed. But as the code is open source, reverse engineering is possible. You will find libraries that use these techniques on the internet (e.g. to [add missing web apis](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader)), but you will not find them listed on http://package.elm-lang.org/.